# DOMDocument() get whole Tag and not only value

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I use `DOMDocument()` to parse html and get the iframes:

```
$content  = '<p>Lorem ip.., </p>
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Fv6sHgq6hFc?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 <p>sed diam volup...orem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            ';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML( $content );            
$lst = $document->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
$videos = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $lst->length; $i++ ) {
 $iframe = $lst->item($i);
 var_dump($iframe);
 /* I want to get "<iframe width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Fv6sHgq6hFc?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>" here */
}
```

How do I get the whole iframe like `<iframe src="..." attribute 1>` or `<iframe src="..." attribute 1></iframe>` ?

Thank You!

Comment: What you want is unclear. Please give us an  HTML example with an iframe and tell us what you want to get inside.

Comment: @M.Page Please have a look at my edits.

Comment: @M.Page I want to get the whole iframe tag putted out currently I am only able to put out its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($lst as $iframe) {
    var_dump($document->saveHtml($iframe));
}
```

Works only with PHP >= 5.3.6

Otherwise:

```
foreach($lst as $iframe) {
    $cloned = $iframe->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
    var_dump($newdoc->saveHTML());
}
```

Comment: I did and got this error: `
Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in`

Comment: Yep. Just checked that. 5.3.3. Is there any other way?

Comment: I did :) and got: 'Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object i'

Comment: Additionally DOMNodeList implements Traversable. It can be used with foreach(). `foreach($lst as $iframe) { ... }`